How to keep same size when save pictures in python matplotlib?
I use code as below to plot graphs and save fig to png files, but all png files are not in the same size (width x height), how can I let all of them in the same size?
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize(20, 10))
fig.savefig('myImage.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)

The png files size (width x height) as below, does anyone help me?


did you try setting figsize in subplots?

do you mean that I have to set figsize = (20, 10) for fixed 6000 x 3000 when dpi is 300?

I am doing some trial and error with different image types. Compression seems to be the main issue...

I only use for png image.

See my answer, I mistook resolution for file size...

I am sorry that I made mistake, I modified my question, I used figsize, they are can not be the same resolutions.

bbox_inches='tight' modifies the shape of the figure so that it fits around the artists you have drawn on it.  If you remove that all your images should be the same size.  If you want to modify what's in the figure to fit the size better, have a look at Constrained Layout
